Taurus tests failing even if still inside success criteria
I'm running tests in an Azure yaml pipeline with a jmx file and using Taurus for running and reporting results.
My pipeline has a parameter of success rate which is being passed like this (among other parameters):
parameters:
  SuccessRate: '97%'

And the part which is calling Taurus is defined like this and using this parameter looks like this:
- task: TaurusRunner@0
        displayName: 'Run Tests'
        inputs:
          taurusConfig: |
          ...
          ...
          reporting:
            - module: junit-xml
              filename: taurus-output/TEST-Taurus.xml
            - module: passfail
              criteria:
               - success<${{ parameters.SuccessRate }}, continue as failed
          ...

- task: PublishTestResults@2
        displayName: 'Publish Test Result'
          inputs:
            testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
            testResultsFiles: 'taurus-output/TEST-Taurus.xml'
            failTaskOnFailedTests: true

The problem is that when I run the tests, there are some tests which are passing at 99.8%, yet the reporting still shows them as failed, even though I expected it to be considered as passed since the criteria if for 97%..
Why are the tests reported as not passing?

Where did you see the failed report? In the Pipeline task: TaurusRunner Output or in the Pipeline Summary -> Tests  tab? Test the same criteria in the TaurusRunner, the task output should show as code 0. Can you share some details about the failed report?

And can you share the Jmeter and  Taurus CLI version you are using in Pipeline?

@KevinLu-MSFT The TaurusRunner@0 is passing with green. PublishTestResults@2 is the one who is failing with red with the error: ##[error]There are one or more test failures detected in result files. Detailed summary of published test results can be viewed in the Tests tab.

I'm using in the pipeline: JMeter 5.6.3, Python 3.8 and Taurus 1.16.32

I'm not sure if that's what happened but my jmx has 4 different requests, and one of them had 99.% success which the runner showed as failure. It maybe calculated it like only 3 out of 4 requests passed which is only 75% success overall.. If that's really the case then that wasn't my intention since the 97% success I want is supposed to be per request and not per the overall number of requests, meaning the I want 99.8% of the single request will be considered as a success, not a failure

Can you see the exit code 0 in the TaurusRunner task? If yes, this means that the passfail module can work as expected. To solve the error in publish test result task, you need to remove the argument: failtaskonfailedtest: true  Then it will show green for entire pipeline run.

It does have exit code 0. Let's say I remove failtaskonfailedtest: true and all requests have 96%, then will it already fail in the run tests step?

Also, is there a way to tell the passfail module to not only return code 0 if the criteria is met, but also give a success notice for the requests even if their success is below 100%?

Thanks for your sharing. I can understand your situation now. And I have added an answer to share more information about your questions. You can check it.

Based on the discussion in the comment, I can fully understand your situation now.
First of all, the TaurusRunner task has already return 0. This means that the Test has passed and Passfail module can work as expected.
The reason for Publish Test Result task failure is related to setting: failTaskOnFailedTests: true. This task will read the test output XML file and upload it. If there are failed tests in the file, the task will fail. It will not follow the Passfail criteria in Taurus Runner task. We can remove this argument in Publish Test Result task to let the task pass.

It does have exit code 0. Let's say I remove failtaskonfailedtest: true and all requests have 96%, then will it already fail in the run tests step?

I can reproduce the same situation.

The root cause of this problem is the different test statistics.
The Taurus Runner task will calculate based on the actual number of tests.
The Tests tab will calculate based on output xml(TEST-Taurus.xml). And the output xml will collect data based on test class(Another word: Request label).
Therefore, we see the difference in the success rate of the tests on both sides.
The Passfail module can only be used for Taurus Runner tasks, and will not affect subsequent Pipeline tasks(e.g. Publish test result task). Therefore, it will be counted based on the actual number of tests. In your case, the Taurus Test should be successful.

Also, is there a way to tell the passfail module to not only return code 0 if the criteria is met, but also give a success notice for the requests even if their success is below 100%?

When you set up the Passfail module, you can directly determine whether the test is successful based on the task running results.
When the exit code is 0(Test Pass), the task running result is Green. And the exit code is 3(Test fail), the task running result is Red.
Test Pass:

Test Fail:


What I meant in the 2nd question is that currently all requests with 100% are shown as "OK" and if a request has even 99.9999% it will be marked as "Failed". Is it possible to tell it to mark the tests as "OK" as long as they meet the criteria?

@CodeMonkey Thanks for your clarification. I can understand now. You need to let the request label to show OK when it meet the criteria. In this case, I am afraid that this is not possible. If the request is not show as 100%, it will show fail state in the request label. The Passfail criteria can work on the overall test result. It can not apply to a single request label.

I cannot reproduce your issue, when I have the following definition:
reporting:
- module: passfail
  criteria:
  - succ<97%, continue as failed

and 98% of successful requests I get the following output:
12:25:07 INFO: Shutting down...
12:25:07 INFO: Post-processing...
12:25:07 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:02
12:25:07 INFO: Samples count: 100, 2.00% failures
12:25:07 INFO: Average times: total 0.000, latency 0.000, connect 0.000
12:25:07 INFO: Percentiles:
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|           0.0 |           0.0 |
|          50.0 |           0.0 |
|          90.0 |           0.0 |
|          95.0 |         0.001 |
|          99.0 |         0.001 |
|          99.9 |         0.014 |
|         100.0 |         0.014 |
+---------------+---------------+
12:25:07 INFO: Request label stats:
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| label         | status |   succ | avg_rt | error |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Debug Sampler |  FAIL  | 98.00% |  0.000 | OK    |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
12:25:07 INFO: Artifacts dir: /tmp/2024-10-10_12-25-02.838635
12:25:07 INFO: Done performing with code: 0

and when I change the criteria to:
reporting:
- module: passfail
  criteria:
  - succ<100%, continue as failed

the output is the following:
12:27:36 INFO: Shutting down...
12:27:36 INFO: Post-processing...
12:27:36 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:02
12:27:36 INFO: Samples count: 100, 2.00% failures
12:27:36 INFO: Average times: total 0.000, latency 0.000, connect 0.000
12:27:36 INFO: Percentiles:
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|           0.0 |           0.0 |
|          50.0 |           0.0 |
|          90.0 |           0.0 |
|          95.0 |           0.0 |
|          99.0 |           0.0 |
|          99.9 |         0.001 |
|         100.0 |         0.001 |
+---------------+---------------+
12:27:36 INFO: Request label stats:
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| label         | status |   succ | avg_rt | error |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Debug Sampler |  FAIL  | 98.00% |  0.000 | OK    |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
12:27:36 WARNING: Alert: succ<100% for 1 sec
12:27:36 WARNING: Failed: succ<100% for 1 sec
12:27:36 WARNING: Automated shutdown
12:27:36 INFO: Artifacts dir: /tmp/2024-10-10_12-27-32.070850
12:27:36 WARNING: Done performing with code: 3

So when the exit status code is 0 it means that the job succeeded, and if its non-zero, i.e. 3 it means that test failed somewhere somehow.
See Exit Codes Taurus documentation chapter for more details in particular and The Complete Taurus Course in general

thats nice but for me it does happen..
